# Telegram Telethon not not showing / printing messages as in print event raw text

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

i am tinkering around with Telethon and was using it to capture live messages in Telegram but when i try to capture some messages in dummy chat group or dummy channel, it somehow won't return the message i've written there. Here is the code i use :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    api_id = 'xxxxxxx'
    api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    chat_id_scalping = [-15xxxxxx]

    client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=chat_id_scalping))
    async def my_event_handler(event):
        try:
            print(event.raw_text)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```

When i run the code it simply let me log in to my phone number, enter the verification code, and state that i am logged in as the correct user. After i test and dump some message on the dummy chat group or channel group (which is stated in the chat_id_scalping) it simply wont return any of the messages. Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

I try and change the chat_id_scalping to all live groups or channels but still same issue, nothing is returned back.

Comment: You can try removing the `chats=` filter until you figure out what those are. Depending where you host, Telegram may also behave funny. Make sure the account you're using is the one you're expecting. [Configure `logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) and remove the `try/except`.

Comment: I tried to remove the chats=filter and fill it directly using the group chat id or channel id, and removed the try/except, but still my terminal is blank when i simply put dummy messages or test it on live group chats :(

Comment: Make sure it's using the account you expect. Try doing something else, like sending a message, to see if other requests work.

Comment: Yep i am sure i am using the account that i expected, and i have been replacing chat_id to various groups / channels or individual chat, but still the issue persist.. i also have checked if my telegram account has restrictions but apparently no restrictions is placed